# 404 running Mvc3 with Mono on Raspberry Pi with Nginx and FastCgi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nginx, mono, fastcgi, raspberry-pi

After lots and lots of hours put into configuring, formatting, reformatting, googling and reading what seems like hundred tutorials I still havent been able to run a MVC3 application on Raspberry Pi.

When I try to access it it throws a 404 error regardless if I try to access it via `http://network_ip` or `http://network_ip/Home/Index`

[image: resource not found]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://shrani.si/f/3j/i7/N22Qi7f/resourcenotfound.png))</sub>

It does the same whether accessed from Nginx or XSP4 server.

My configuration:

**nginx**

```
server {
  listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

  root /var/www;

  # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
  server_name localhost;

  access_log   /var/log/nginx/localhost.log;

  location / {
     root /var/www/;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    #fastcgi_index Home/Index;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

MVC3 app should be deployed correctly (deleted Entity Framework references, copied Mvc references).

Im running Mono 2.10.8.1

Thank you

Comment: mvc3 is not compatible with mono 2.10, please upgrade Mono

Comment: Here http://sourcecodebean.com/archives/deploying-your-asp-net-mvc3-site-on-mono/1589 says it is. Here as well http://www.codewithmac.com/2013/05/asp-net-mvc-on-your-raspberry-pi/

Comment: they were maybe just lucky, mono 2.10 is too old